# "Home Site" for iOS App

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Could a feature be considered for the iOS app where you can set one of your "sites" as the home/landing page of the app when the application initially loads?

For example, I'd love to default mine to the Japanese Usage site, and only pull up the Feeds page or other sites when necessary.

Answer (score -1):

iOS's standard of behavior (and my personal preference) is that an application should pick up as near as possible to where the user left off when it's reopened. The app should behave as if it was just waiting in the background.

Thus, the idea of showing the same "landing page" every time the app is resumed doesn't mesh well with what users will expect. It will feel to many of them like information is being lost.

I don't think that this feature would be a good addition to the app.

Comment: That functionality is there. If I leave the app to look at something else, and return shortly thereafter, the page I was last on is still in view. I am talking about a default site to load on initial loading of the application. Currently, you are shown the "Feed" page when you first load the application. I don't find this page particularly useful and wouldn't mind skipping it entirely, though perhaps I am the minority, not the majority.

Comment: I don't understand now; you want it to go to your site _only_ the _very first_ time you open the app? How would it know which site? You haven't even signed in yet. And why would that be useful, since every other time, you'd go back to where you left off?

Comment: By "when you first load the application" I meant whenever the app is launched where it was previously not running on the device (for instance, after rebooting/updating the device, or when relaunching the app after it has been quit, etc). Currently, the Feed page is shown and I must pull up the sidebar menu to navigate to an actual SE site. 95% of the time I read the Japanese Usage page-- as such, I would like an option to set this site as the app's home page, rather than the Feed page. I do read other SE sites (SO and UX at work), but I don't think I will ever access them via my phone.